# How to check php value equal or with differents conditions

Tags: php

I want to solve this little problem :

```
if($risque >= '1' && $lang !== 'fr' && ($country !== 'Spain' || 'France'))
        $msg_error = 'error';
```

My goal is to check if the risque is equal or superior to 1 **and** if lang is different than fr, **and** if country is different than Spain or France

So if risque is 0, no msg_error, if risque is 1 and lang = fr but country is Belgium, so show the msg_error

I'm not sure with the priority and the code !== and separator ...

Thanks

Comment: This does not work as you expect in PHP: `$country !== 'Spain' || 'France'`. See AbraCadaver's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
if($risque >= '1' && $lang !== 'fr' && (!in_array($country,array('Spain','France')))
```

Using [in_array()](https://www.php.net/in_array) would solve your problem to check for multiple values.

Comment: +1 Was going to add to my answer but you beat me to it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to repeat the evaluation of `$country` and you will need the `&&` because if the first condition fails then the `||` will not be evaluated:

```
if($risque >= 1 && $lang !== 'fr' && ($country !== 'Spain' && $country !== 'France')) {
        $msg_error = 'error';
}
```

Comment: Note: the parentheses around the country comparison aren't necessary here.

Comment: Agreed, but left for visual grouping.

Answer (score 0):

```
if($risque >= 1 && $lang != "fr" && $country != "Spain" && $country != "France")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if( $risque >= '1' 
    && $lang !== 'fr' 
    && $country !== 'Spain' 
    && $country !== 'France' ) 
{
  // Code
}
```

Comment: if `$country` is 'France', the first part of your `||` is true and so the second check is not evaluated.

Comment: Will fail for `$country = 'France'`

Answer (score 0):

Your if statement should be written this way:

```
if($risque >= 1 && $lang != "fr" && $country != "Spain" && $country != "France")
    $msg_error = "error";
```

When you are comparing an Integer value (in $risque), always remove the "'" since "'" refers to a string / character instead of refering to an Integer value.

Answer (score -1):

I guess this should do:

```
if($risque >= 1 && $lang == 'fr' && ($country != 'Spain' || $country != 'France')){
    $msg_error = "error";
}
```

Notice that I remove "'" from $risque and compare $lang using  ==

Comment: Will fail for `$country = 'France'`

Comment: I don't see how would fail in this case

Comment: See by [testing it](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/02bae9c6552f46dcc8d8bd9984f701e26cafce14)

Comment: Yeah, now I can see why. My bad!